# Update layout after download

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service

I am starting a new `Service` to download a database file in an `Activity` and I also have a `Fragment` inside the `Activity` that uses the data from the downloaded database file to set up its layout. So, is there any way or method to know that the `IntentService` has finished downloading and then I can attach the `Fragment` to the `Activity`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, DownloadService.class);
startService(intent);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.startContainer,new ChartFragment()).commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `BroadcastReceiver`. As @HendraWD stated in his answer, there are many other ways to get notified about download is finished, you might try `BroadcastReceiver` in your case.

So inside your `Activity` create a `BroadcastReceiver` like this.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Launch your Fragment here
    }
};
```

Check the `onReceive` function of your `BroadcastReceiver`. The `onReceive` function will be called when the download finishes if you register the `BroadcastReceiver` and then notify back properly. I'm adding some code example here.

In the `onCreate` function of your `Activity`, register the `BroadcastReceiver` first.

```
registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"));
```

Now in the `onDestroy` function in your `Activity` unregister the receiver.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

Now from the `Service` you started, when the download is finished, you might need to notify back to your `Activity` about that. So, you need to send the broadcast from your `Service` like this.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks it solved the issue but it still don't understand the working i have to do some studying.

Comment: This is simple. You need to have a receiver to keep listening for the download to be finished and when the download is finished, you just need to send the broadcast to the receiver. As soon as the receiver receives the broadcast, the `onReceive` function is called.

Comment: Never unregisterReceiver on `onDestroy`! It is never guarantee to be called

Answer (score 1):

Register a BroadcastReceiver in your Activity something like:

```
 BroadcastReceiver  myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // do my stuff
}
};

registerReceiver(myReceiver , new IntentFilter("com.myapp.DOWNLOADCOMPLETE"));
```

Then in your service send the broadcast:

```
// use intent to send broadcast
Intent i = new Intent("com.myapp.DOWNLOADCOMPLETE");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

You can also putExtras on your intent if you need to pass some values.

A googled tutorial on Android Services and background processing can be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial  link

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to notify UI from a service.

1. [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
2. Publish/subscribe event bus([Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/), [EventBus](https://greenrobot.github.io/EventBus/))
3. Observable Pattern([RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava), [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid))

If you are not sure what each of that is, you can start with just BroadcastReceiver. It is the standard way that Android provide.

Here is a simple example how to do it with. Your Service will be looks like this:

```
public class YourService extends IntentService {

    public YourService() {
        super("YourService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //your process..

        //process done
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("Your filter");
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("param you want to pass", "value");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
}
```

Here is your activity looks like

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }

    BroadcastReceiver yourBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //do something
            Log.d(YourActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "broadcast receiver called");
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(yourBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("Your filter"));
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(yourBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

I am using [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) here because it is more efficient and secure